# Sorting individual rows in Pandas DataFrame and returning column names

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame like this (much larger)

```
|Date      | Team1 | Team2 | Team3 |
|----------|-------|-------|-------|
|1/20/2020 | 10.5  |  12   |  10.1 |
|1/27/2020 | 11.2  |  11.1 |  11.9 |
```

And I want to create a new column that contains the list of teams for each date in the ascending order of their records.

```
|Date      | Team1 | Team2 | Team3 | Rank                        |
|----------|-------|-------|-------|-----------------------------|
|1/20/2020 | 10.5  |  12   |  10.1 |  ['Team3', 'Team1', 'Team2']|
|1/27/2020 | 11.2  |  11.1 |  11.9 |  ['Team2', 'Team1', 'Team3']|
```

Is there an efficient way to achieve this without constructing arrays from each row. sorting, finding column names from sorted indices etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) on teams columns to find the order to sort values by row, and then you can use the order to reorder column names to give what you need:

```
# filter team columns
teams = df.filter(like='Team')

# argsort on teams columns by row and reorder columns with it
df['Rank'] = teams.columns[teams.values.argsort(1)].tolist()
df

        Date  Team1  Team2  Team3                   Rank
0  1/20/2020   10.5   12.0   10.1  [Team3, Team1, Team2]
1  1/27/2020   11.2   11.1   11.9  [Team2, Team1, Team3]
```

Comment: Smart idea Psidom. Works great. Thanks!